# Cloud bees, create db's tables

Tags: cloudbees

After I've done developing my web site using Hibernate and Struts2, now I want to put it on Cloudbees hoster, the problem is that I don't know how to create my data base's tables?!!
I used the method shown in this video to create my tables: http://vimeo.com/33445098 But it doesn't work!!
It shows how to connect to my server by using MySQL WorkBench, when I created new Server instance the connection couldn't be established, although I used the appropriate informations.

Thank very much :)

Answer (score 0):

After days of looking around on the web I found this, it's very useful
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWE6s_FQBwA